# How to compare different arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to show the email address, first and last names of users who are not registered in my new database.

I selected three columns of my old database and three columns of my new database. I created two arrays and each receives the result of the query.

But when the comparing is displaying all users, the comparison is not made.

Check my code:

```
while($array = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
$portal_old[] = $array;
}
while($array2 = $resultado2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
$portal_new[] = $array2;
}
foreach ($portal_old as $portal) {
   if(!in_array($portal, $portal_new)){
    $result[] = $portal;
  }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question a bit; if you disagree with the edit, you can roll it back; click on the "edited ... ago" link below your post to do that. Clicking on that link will take you to the edit history, where you can roll back to previous versions of your post. Meanwhile, enjoy your stay!

Comment: Selecting 'three' columns from each?  Is that not your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming email address should be able to uniquely identify a registered user, you can use email address as a key as you build your array of results from each database.

```
while($array = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $portal_old[$array['email']] = $array;
}
while($array2 = $resultado2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $portal_new[$array2['email']] = $array2;
}
```

In order for this to work, you will need to either use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` instead of `MYSQLI_NUM` when fetching, and specify the name of the email column when building your array, or if you are using `MYSQLI_NUM`, specify the numeric index of the email column.

Then you can use [array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to easily find the result you are looking for.

```
$result = array_diff_key($portal_old, $portal_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, John Smith here gets in $result while Joe Black doesn't:

```
<?php
$name = array(0 => 'john', 1 => 'smith');
$portal_old[] = $name;
$name = array(0 => 'joe', 1 => 'black');
$portal_old[] = $name;

//print_r($portal_old);

//shows: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => john [1] => smith ) [1] => Array ( [0] => joe [1] => black ) ) 

$name = array(0 => 'jason', 1 => 'mill');
$portal_new[] = $name;
$name = array(0 => 'joe', 1 => 'black');
$portal_new[] = $name;

//print_r($portal_new);

//shows: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => jason [1] => mill ) [1] => Array ( [0] => joe [1] => black ) ) 

foreach($portal_old as $key=>$value) {
    if(!in_array($value[0], $portal_new[0]) && !in_array($value[1], $portal_new[1])) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);

//shows:  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => john [1] => smith ) ) 

?>
```

It's because the results of $portal_old and $portal_new are multidimensional arrays, you need to compare by looking inside the arrays of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
$i = $j = 0;
while($array = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
$portal_old[$i][$array['0'].' | '.$array['1'].' | '.$array['2']] = $array;
}
while($array2 = $resultado2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
$portal_new[$j][$array2['0'].' | '.$array2['1'].' | '.$array2['2']] = $array2;
}
// Get only array keys
$old_arr_key = array_keys($portal_old[0]);
$new_arr_key = array_keys($portal_new[0]);

// Result
$result = array_diff($new_arr_key,$old_arr_key);
print_r($result);
```